# How can I check the Tomcat HTTP connector status in spring boot?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

If I use a standalone Tomcat, I can check the detailed list of threads and url(s) in the HTTP connector status (under "http-nio-8080"), using the link like: http://localhost:8080/manager/status.

This is quite helpful that I can check if the Tomcat is busy handling requests.

Is there a similar way to check this information for spring boot embedded Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by leveraging the power of **Actuators**. And all you need to do is to simply add the dependency of `spring-boot-actuator` into your pom file.

Actuators enable production-ready features to a Spring Boot application – without having to actually implement these things yourself. They’re mainly used to expose different types of information about the running application – health, metrics, info, dump, env etc.

After starting up your application, visit the endpoint such as http://localhost:8080/dump and you can see what you want.

For more information about other endpoints provided by actuator, please refer to [47. Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html).

If you want to visualize and interact with actuator endpoints, please refer to [Spring Boot Admin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-admin-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/configuration-monitoring-management.html#_spring_boot_admin).

Hope this helps you!